# Draw rectangles based on values in list matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose there's a list

```
lst = [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]
```

I'd like to draw:

[image]

So here's the code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
 
ax.axvspan(-0.5, 2.5, alpha=0.4, color='yellow')
ax.axvspan(2.5, 4.5, alpha=0.4, color='red')
ax.axvspan(4.5, 5.5, alpha=0.4, color='yellow')
ax.axvspan(5.5, 7.5, alpha=0.4, color='red')
```

However, for longer lists, it takes forever to achieve that. Is there a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a bar plot, where the bar height is constant and the color changes based on the values in `lst`.

```
lst = [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]

plt.bar(
    x = range(len(lst)),
    height = [1.0 for _ in lst],
    color = ['yellow' if n == 0 else 'red' for n in lst],
    width = 1
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself:

```
def draw_rects(lst):
    res = [list(y) for x, y in groupby(lst)]
    csum = np.cumsum(list(map(len, res))) - 0.5
    vals = [key for key, _group in groupby(lst)]
    
    mapping = {0 : "green", 1 : "purple", 2 : "red", 3 : "yellow"}
    cols = [mapping[x] if x in mapping else x for x in vals]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots() 

    ax.axvspan(-0.5, csum[0], alpha = 0.4, color = cols[0])
    for i in range(len(csum)-1):
        ax.axvspan(csum[i], csum[i+1], alpha = 0.4, color = cols[i+1]) = 0.4, color = cols[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by iterating and depending upon consecutive values. It would be faster for longer lists.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lst = [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]

plt.bar(
    x = range(len(lst)),
    height = [0.8 for _ in lst],
    color = ['blue' if n == 0 else 'green' for n in lst],
    width = 1
)
plt.show()
```

[image: Output of example code]

Answer (score 0):

Using [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html):

```
lst = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1])

x = np.arange(len(lst), dtype= float)
x[ [0, -1]] += [-0.5, 0.5]

plt.fill_between(x, 0, 1-lst, step='mid', color='yellow')
plt.fill_between(x, 0, lst, step='mid', color='red')
```

Note that if you set the background yellow, you only need to plot the red.

[image]